# I cannot get the page to render for the Django Apps tutorial

Tags: python, django, http, server, django-views

I am using the django tutorial to create my first polls app and to learn Django

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/intro/tutorial01/

Here are the files I have created so far:

[image: my app's file structure]

in `mysite/urls.py` I have this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path("polls/", include("polls.urls")),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
]
```

In `polls/urls.py` I have this:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
]
```

And in `polls/views.py` I have the following:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```

I have been trying with  http://localhost:8000/polls/ and it still doesn't work! Any thoughts please on why that might be?

[image: booo!]

I have debugged in every way I can but everything looks correct to me. I am using GitHub's IDE but I don't think that should be the problem.

Comment: `from django.shortcuts import render`

I added this in to the `views.py` file as it had previously been removed by me, according to a YouTube video - but sadly, it still did not work :(((

Comment: looks like your server is not running, did you run it? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/intro/tutorial01/#the-development-server

Comment: I'm also thinking the same above, that your server is not running. please try to the server given below command by @sachin and after trying that it does not work then please push your code on Git Hub as a public repo.
thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are not running your server.
Run this command:

```
 python manage.py runserver
```